# How to change the variables in this integral?

Tags: change-of-variable

I want to calculate the following integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(r_1,r_2)}{\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert}\; r_1^2 r_2^2\; dr_1 dr_2 \tag{1}
$$
also I intend to use the following change variables
$$
r=\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
R=\frac{m_1r_1+m_2r_2}{m_1+m_2} \tag{3}
$$

to transform $(1)$ using $(2)$ and $(3)$, assuming we know the form of $f(r,R)$ as
$$
f(r,R)=\text{exp}(-ar-br^2)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive parameters.
Well we know from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$
r_1=R-\frac{m_2 r}{(m_1+m_2)} \tag{4}
$$
and
$$
r_2=R-\frac{m_1 r}{(m_1+m_2)} \tag{5}
$$
Should I simply replace $r_1^2$ and $r_2^2$ by $(4)$ and $(5)$? and what about differentials $dr_1$ and $dr_2$?

Comment: At first glance, unless $f(r_1,r_2)=O(|r_1-r_2|^a)$ for some $a>0$ the integral is not well-defined (it diverges). As for changing variables, notice that the integral on the region $r_1>r_2$ equals that on the region $r_2>r_1$ by symmetry, so you can drop the absolute value.

Comment: Most importantly, how can we help you compute this without an explicit formula for $f$ ?

Comment: @Medo I added the form of $f(r,R)$

Comment: @Wisdom Do you have that $b>0$ so that's a decaying exponential?

Comment: @Alan Yes, I added this to the question

Comment: @Wisdom. Do you need an exact computation, or an estimate in terms of $a,b$ ?

Comment: @Alan absolutely exact. However I didn't get your mean about "an estimate in terms of a,b"

Comment: That last question was from @Medo